# SQL buscando registros apartir de uma Data e Hora

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Tenho o seguinte SQL:

```
select * from tb_valores
where
DATA >= '14/12/17' and
HORA >= '16:34:00')
```

Gostaria de trazer todos os registros partir dessa data e hora.

O problema é que se eu tiver registros como:

```
'14/12/17' '10:20:00'
'14/12/17' '13:20:00'
'14/12/17' '16:32:00'
'18/12/17' '08:00:00'
```

ele não traz esses registros.

Comment: Assim não funciona?  select * from tb_valores
where
(DATA >= '14/12/17 '') and ( HORA >= '16:34:00')

Comment: Todos os registros listados são menor que "16:34:00", por isso não está trazendo resultados. O outro erro é com a sintaxe SQL.

Comment: Na sua tabela esse campo DATA é um `Date`? e esse campo Hora e um `Time`?

Comment: Se possível adicione a estrutura da sua tabela e o tipo de dados que são esses campos, se você quer pegar a hora é simples, apenas pegue a data, não ficou muito claro para mim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiago, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_valores WHERE (DATA > '14/12/17' OR (DATA = '14/12/17' AND HORA >= '16:34:00'))
```

Dessa forma a consulta buscará todos dados com data é maior que "14/12/17", que por consequência serão maiores que "14/12/17 16:34:00", ou os dados com data igual a "14/12/17" mas hora maior ou igual a "16:34:00".

Answer (score 0):

Assim não funciona?

```
select * from tb_valores where (DATA >= '14/12/17 '') and ( HORA >= '16:34:00')
```

Comment: Jovani, não funciona, pois se eu tiver valores inferiores a hora '16:34:00' ele não busca.

Answer (score 0):

Tiago, 
O código do Jovani roda, validei ele agora.

apenas tira uma aspa logo após do 17, que funciona.

Deixa assim:

```
    select * from tb_valores where (DATA >= '14/12/17') and ( HORA >= '16:34:00')
```

Ao invés de assim:

```
    select * from tb_valores where (DATA >= '14/12/17 '') and ( HORA >= '16:34:00')
```

Se ainda assim não funcionar, manda o Create Statment da sua tabela.